# How do I align things properly in Android?

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to layout a simple CardView, where there is text on the top, and beneath that, there are a couple of those "buttons". But I can't even seem to get the layouts to align properly, and I've done it in the past (a while ago, I must admit) using layout_above and layout_below but they don't seem to be available anymore. So I've tried it some other ways, based on what I learned from the docs, but I don't think I learned much... clearaly...

To better explain what my code is trying to do, here's a pic:

[image: CardView with text on the top, a separator and button on the bottom.]

Instead of seeing what you can see in the pic above, all I see is a two layouts overlapping and the button appearing ontop of both layouts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0.7dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="1.0dp"
    android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/linearLayoutBackgroundColor">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cardViewTextItem"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/cardText"
            android:padding="7dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/secondLinearLayoutBackgroundColor">
        <Button android:text="DETAILS" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@color/cardview_light_background" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

layout_above and layout_below only available within RelativeLayout. Your xml should be like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    /*some attributes*/ >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/button"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrap everything in a `linearLayout` and remove your nested `Relativelayout.`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     >
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0.7dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="1.0dp"
    android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cardViewTextItem"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/cardText"
            android:padding="7dp"/>
          <Button android:text="DETAILS" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@color/cardview_light_background" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this , it is easy

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dip"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/Widget.CardContent.TitleBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textWelCome"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="cardText"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/Widget.CardContent.TitleBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/textWelCome2"
                    android:layout_width="150dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="175dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:text="DETAILS"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```